# how to transpose rows to columns for the grouped data?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

While doing the employees and supervisors analysis, I got in trouble with the BigQuery statements.

```
SELECT SupervisorName, Emp_Status, COUNT(DISTINCT EmpNO)AS NUMBER
FROM 
(SELECT
  EmpNO,
  EmpName,
  (CASE WHEN TerminationDate IS NULL THEN 'Active'
    ELSE 'Terminated'
  END
    )AS Emp_Status, 
    DateOfBirth,
    DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),DateOfBirth,YEAR) AS Age,
    SupervisorName

    FROM `Table1`
)
GROUP BY SupervisorName, Emp_Status
ORDER BY SupervisorName, NUMBER DESC
```

The result is shown below:

```
    Row SupervisorName  Emp_Status  NUMBER  
1   null            Terminated       321
2   null            Active           2
3   Ahearn          Active           3
4   Ahearn          Terminated       2
5   Allen           Active           6
6   Allen           Terminated       3
......
```

How can I change it to like this:

```
    Row SupervisorName  Active    Termination   Total
    1       Null            2          321           323
    2       Ahearn          3          2             5 
    3       Allen           6          3             9
......
```

Comment: I also would like to add a time filter, but if I add the code like WHERE LastHireDate BETWEEN '01-01-2018' AND CURRENT_DATE(), then there is an error saying Could not cast literal "01-01-2018" to type DATE at [15:30]. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe that's what you want

```
select
    SupervisorName,
    count(distinct if(TerminationDate is null, EmpNO, null)) as active,
    count(distinct if(TerminationDate is null, null, EmpNO)) as terminated,
    count(distinct EmpNO) as dist_total,
    count(*) as total
from 
    `Table1`
where
    --  you should use keyword "date" and iso8601 format
    LastHireDate between    date'2018-01-01'
                            and current_date()
group by
    1
order by
    1, 4 desc
```

Comment: Yes: [conditional expressions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions)

Comment: Great, yours is right. This is exactly what I want. Had no idea Bigquery has such many functions.

Answer (score 1):

The standard pattern here is to use SUM and CASE to get the result -- as below:

```
SELECT 
  SupervisorName, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Emp_Status = 'Active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Active,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Emp_Status = 'Terminated' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Termination,
  COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM (
  SELECT
    EmpNO,
    EmpName,
    CASE WHEN TerminationDate IS NULL THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Terminated' END AS Emp_Status, 
    DateOfBirth,
    DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),DateOfBirth,YEAR) AS Age,
    SupervisorName
  FROM `Table1`
)
GROUP BY SupervisorName
```

Note, I left the same sub-query you had, but as given you don't actually need a sub-query, you can just change the CASE statement to look at termination date instead of the string you created in the sub-query.

I assume your actual code is more complicated so I left it like this.

Comment: Awesome! BTW, do you know how to add a time filter if I would like to connect it to data studio?

Comment: @Sandy you can add in a where clause if you want

Comment: I realized that there is a bug in your codes. Or I forgot to say that some of the employees' ids are duplicates. So that you cannot simply sum the Active, you should count the distinct employee number. I don't know how to figure it out either.

Comment: @Sandy - so update your question with those "details" and let clear how you want to count such duplicates!!

Comment: @Sandy -- just group by the employee id in the sub-query.